# CGAL filtered kernel without lazy evaluation

Tags: geometry, thread-safety, cgal

I've been studying CGAL and I am having trouble trying to define a kernel that satisfies what I need.

I need a kernel that is thread safe but, at the same time, I want to store exact coordinates.

If I understood CGAL documentation correctly:

- The exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel is thread safe, but it stores coordinates as double values.
- The exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel stores the exact coordinates, but is not thread safe (because of the lazy number type).
- CGAL::Simple_cartesian is thread-safe and stores the coordinates exactly. However, it is much slower for my application.

I basically concluded that I need something like:

`CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<mpq_class>>`

(a kernel that uses filtered interval arithmetic for performance, stores the exact coordinates (that will be used when the filter fails) and does not use a lazy number type).

I think this kernel would be slower than exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel, but it would be thread-safe and much faster than a non-filtered kernel. (furthermore, I think lazy number types would not be so useful for my application because I want to output the exact coordinates anyway and, thus, they will have to be computed at some point -- that is, the only "optimization" I need is fast filtered predicates)

The problem is: I tried to compile a test application with this kernel and the compilation always fails. Is there a reason why I cannot create a filtered kernel that keeps not only the floating-point intervals but also the exact coordinates?

PS: I am using CGAL 4.10 on Linux

Thanks!

---

Update:
Minimum example that fails:

```
#include <CGAL/gmpxx.h> //needed to use mpq_class as the field type
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Filtered_kernel.h> 
#include <CGAL/Lazy_kernel.h> 

//typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel   Kernel; //works...
//typedef CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>> Kernel; //works...
//typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<mpq_class> Kernel; //works!
//typedef CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>> Kernel; //works! (but Gmpq is not thread safe, while mpq_class is)
typedef CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<mpq_class>> Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3                                       Point_3;

int main() {
    Point_3 a(0,0,0);
    Point_3 b(1,0,0);
    Point_3 c(0,1,0);
    Point_3 d(1,1,1);

    //The code compiles if I remove the line below
    CGAL::Orientation orientationP0Triangle = CGAL::orientation(a,b,c,d);
}
```

Error message:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Cartesian_converter.h:35:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Filtered_kernel.h:27,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h:29,
                 from cgalSimpleExample.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/NT_converter.h: In instantiation of ‘NT2 CGAL::NT_converter<NT1, NT2>::operator()(const NT1&) const [with NT1 = __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>; NT2 = CGAL::Gmpq]’:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Cartesian_converter.h:293:45:   required from ‘typename K2::Point_3 CGAL::Cartesian_converter<K1, K2, Converter>::operator()(const typename K1::Point_3&) const [with K1 = CGAL::Type_equality_wrapper<CGAL::Cartesian_base_no_ref_count<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>, CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >, CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >; K2 = CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>; Converter = CGAL::NT_converter<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>, CGAL::Gmpq>; typename K2::Point_3 = CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >; typename K1::Point_3 = CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >]’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Filtered_predicate.h:175:27:   required from ‘CGAL::Filtered_predicate<EP, AP, C2E, C2A, Protection>::result_type CGAL::Filtered_predicate<EP, AP, C2E, C2A, Protection>::operator()(const Args& ...) const [with Args = {CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> >, true> >, CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> >, true> >, CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> >, true> >, CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> >, true> >}; EP = CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Orientation_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq> >; AP = CGAL::CartesianKernelFunctors::Orientation_3<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >; C2E = CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Type_equality_wrapper<CGAL::Cartesian_base_no_ref_count<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>, CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >, CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::NT_converter<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>, CGAL::Gmpq> >; C2A = CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Type_equality_wrapper<CGAL::Cartesian_base_no_ref_count<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>, CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >, CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false> >, CGAL::NT_converter<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>, CGAL::Interval_nt<false> > >; bool Protection = true; CGAL::Filtered_predicate<EP, AP, C2E, C2A, Protection>::result_type = CGAL::Sign]’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/internal/Static_filters/Orientation_3.h:170:41:   required from ‘CGAL::internal::Static_filters_predicates::Orientation_3<K_base>::result_type CGAL::internal::Static_filters_predicates::Orientation_3<K_base>::operator()(const Point_3&, const Point_3&, const Point_3&, const Point_3&) const [with K_base = CGAL::Filtered_kernel_base<CGAL::Type_equality_wrapper<CGAL::Cartesian_base_no_ref_count<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>, CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >, CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > > >; CGAL::internal::Static_filters_predicates::Orientation_3<K_base>::result_type = CGAL::Sign; CGAL::internal::Static_filters_predicates::Orientation_3<K_base>::Point_3 = CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >]’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Kernel/global_functions_internal_3.h:860:45:   required from ‘typename K::Orientation CGAL::internal::orientation(const typename K::Point_3&, const typename K::Point_3&, const typename K::Point_3&, const typename K::Point_3&, const K&) [with K = CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > >; typename K::Orientation = CGAL::Sign; typename K::Point_3 = CGAL::Point_3<CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > > >]’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/Kernel/global_functions_3.h:1047:47:   required from ‘typename K::Orientation CGAL::orientation(const CGAL::Point_3<R>&, const CGAL::Point_3<R>&, const CGAL::Point_3<R>&, const CGAL::Point_3<R>&) [with K = CGAL::Filtered_kernel<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<__gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]> > >; typename K::Orientation = CGAL::Sign]’
cgalSimpleExample.cpp:19:69:   required from here
/usr/local/include/CGAL/NT_converter.h:41:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>&)’
         return NT2(a);
                     ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/NT_converter.h:41:21: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Gmp_coercion_traits.h:33:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Gmpz.h:33,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/internal/Exact_type_selector.h:36,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Filtered_kernel.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h:29,
                 from cgalSimpleExample.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:193:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(const string&, int)
   Gmpq(const std::string& str, int base = 10)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:193:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘const string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:174:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(const CGAL::Gmpfr&)
   Gmpq(const Gmpfr &f)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:174:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘const CGAL::Gmpfr&’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:168:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(double)
   Gmpq(double d)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:168:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘double’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:161:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(const CGAL::Gmpz&, const CGAL::Gmpz&)
   Gmpq(const Gmpz& n, const Gmpz& d)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:161:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:155:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(long unsigned int, long unsigned int)
   Gmpq(unsigned long n, unsigned long d)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:155:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:149:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(long int, long unsigned int)
   Gmpq(signed long n, unsigned long d)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:149:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:139:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(int, int)
   Gmpq(int n, int d)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:139:3: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:136:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(const CGAL::Gmpz&)
   Gmpq(const Gmpz& n)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:136:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘const CGAL::Gmpz&’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:124:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(long long int)
   Gmpq(long long n)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:124:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘long long int’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:116:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(long long unsigned int)
   Gmpq(unsigned long long n)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:116:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘long long unsigned int’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:104:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(long unsigned int)
   Gmpq(unsigned long n)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:104:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘long unsigned int’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:101:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(long int)
   Gmpq(long n)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:101:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘long int’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:98:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(unsigned int)
   Gmpq(unsigned int n)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:98:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘unsigned int’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:95:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(int)
   Gmpq(int n)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:95:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘int’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:92:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(const __mpq_struct*)
   Gmpq(const mpq_t q)
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:92:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘const __mpq_struct*’
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:90:3: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq()
   Gmpq() {}
   ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:90:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:69:7: note: CGAL::Gmpq::Gmpq(const CGAL::Gmpq&)
 class Gmpq
       ^
/usr/local/include/CGAL/GMP/Gmpq_type.h:69:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const __gmp_expr<__mpq_struct [1], __mpq_struct [1]>’ to ‘const CGAL::Gmpq&’
```

Comment: Copying the compiler error message here would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question with a minimum example and with the error message.

Comment: I can reproduce it.  I fixed it by making sure GMPXX is discovered by CMake at installation time.  This has the consequence to enable the #define CGAL_USE GMPXX in <CGAL/compiler_config.h>, which in turn makes Filtered_kernel work here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution: I should've compiled my program with the flag CGAL_USE_GMPXX